# mplayer playing gif animation at full screen?

Tags: fullscreen, gif, animated-gif, mplayer, raspbian

I'm not familiar with mplayer and the tons of option seem like a jungle to me, when all I want to do is show an endless looped gif animation at full screen on my RPi running raspbian.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I am now working in Windows and using

```
mplayer -fs –mf fps=1:type=jpeg *.jpg mf://*.jpg  –vo direct3d, -ao dsound-sub-fuzziness 1 -loop 100
```

to play jpg file in mplayer in fullscreen mode. I did't test on linux but i think

```
mplayer -fs –mf fps=1:type=gif *.gif mf://*.jpg  -ao dsound-sub-fuzziness 1 -loop 100
```

should work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I video DJ using the RPi.  Making `mplayer` full-screen is often harder than it should be.  The switch to make `mplayer` full-screen is `-fs`.  The problem is that many video outputs (`-vo`) do not support full-screen.  If the `-vo` does not support `-fs`, I often get around this by using the RCA connection instead of the HDMI on a screen that does not display the entire frame.  Try `mplayer -fs file.gif` and report back.  Which `-vo` are you using?